# How to get to the SSL/TLS internals from Python?

Tags: python, ssl

I am implementing the XMPP protocol in Python (2.7 and 3.2) and I found one important thing stopping me from making the implementation fully compliant.

The current specification ([RFC 6120](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html)) requires implementation of the SCRAM-SHA-1-PLUS SASL mechanism ([RFC 5802](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5802)), which, in turn, requires the 'tls-unique' channel binding ([RFC 5929](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5929)), which is defined as:

> Description: The first TLS Finished message sent (note: the Finished
> struct, not the TLS record layer message containing it) in the most
> recent TLS handshake of the TLS connection being bound to

Python doesn't seem to provide this piece of information directly, but I know it may be obtained via the OpenSSL API, used internally by Python.

Is there any way to get the 'SSL' pointer for a SSL socket wrapper, so I could use it via the ctypes module or from my own extension module? I cannot find anything like that with the header files installed with Python.

Is there any third-party TLS module for Python providing such API, but keeping the general Python SSL API?

Or is the only way to do it, to extract the SSL code from Python and bundle a patched copy of it with my own package?

**Update:** I have created a Python feature request for this functionality: http://bugs.python.org/issue12551
I am still looking for a 'ready to use' solution, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems the easiest way to get the data from the Python `SSLSocket` is to fix the standard Python library. So I did it, the patch will be included in Python 3.3.

http://bugs.python.org/issue12551#msg140450

Comment: Jacek: thanks for doing this, and so early on. I wish other languages and servers had people like you to add this feature in the intervening 3.5 years!

Answer (score 0):

This hopefully will save you some time.

Python SASL resources:

1. [Suelta](https://github.com/dwd/Suelta) pure-python SASL library (probably your best bet)
2. [python-ldap's SASL implementation](http://python-ldap.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/python-ldap/python-ldap/Lib/ldap/sasl.py?view=markup)
3. [Apache qpidc's SASL wrapper](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/qpid/trunk/qpid/python/qpid/sasl.py) around their compartmentalized [Cyrus-SASL](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/qpid/trunk/qpid/extras/sasl/) code.
4. [python-cyrus](http://oss.netfarm.it/python-cyrus.php) looks to be a fairly robust wrapper around Cyrus-SASL

Comment: It seems none of these supports SCRAM-SHA-1-PLUS with channel binding. I don't even see a mention of  SCRAM-SHA-1 (no channel binding) implementation.
I already have a working pure python SASL implementation, the only functionality that it misses and I don't know how to implement easily is the 'tls-unique' channel binding.
I don't want a dependence on any external non-python modules. And even a SASL implementation with channel binding won't help if I have no means to pass channel binding data from my TLS connection to it.

Comment: Suelta appears to have SCRAM-HMAC-PLUS with tls-unique handling, SCRAM-SHA-1-PLUS seems like it'd be pretty easy to implement given the existing code.

Comment: I am looking at the Suelta code under the provided link and cannot find anything that would provide the channel-binding data. That much I have already implemented (and probably better documented). Suelta provides less than I already have.

Still this helps nothing with the core problem: how to get the channel binding data from python.